# Пагинация сбивается при нажатии

Tags: angular

Проблема в том, что когда происходит клик, нумерация страниц чего-то смещается. Когда я нажимаю на 3-ю страницу, нумерация страниц должна иметь значение 41-51, но почему-то прыгает на 23-33.

[image]

EpisodePageComponent

```
export class EpisodePageComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  episodes: IEpisode[];
  page: number = 1;
  info: IInfo

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.handlePage();
  }

  handlePage(event?: PageEvent) {
    if (event) {
      this.page = event.pageIndex + 1
    }

    this._setQueryPage();
    this._loadEpisodes();
  }

  _loadEpisodes(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({episode}) => {
      this.episodes = episode.results;
      this.info = episode.info;
    })
  }

  _setQueryPage(): void {
    const queryParams: Params = {page: this.page};
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    })
  }
}
```

episode-page.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="episodes.length > 0">
  <mat-paginator class="pagination"
    (page)="handlePage($event)"
    [length]="info.count"
    [pageSize]="episodes.length"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[20]"
    aria-label="Select page">
  </mat-paginator>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`23-33` — обозначает 11 записей на странце о чем оно и пишет (items per page 11) и открыта третья страница:

```
 1 - 11  // 1-ая страница
12 - 22  // 2-я страница
23 - 33  // 3-я страница
```

Если у вас лишь одна опция в `pageSizeOptions` равная 20 то и в
`pageSize` должно быть 20:

```
[pageSize]= "20" // правильно
[pageSize]="episodes.length" // 11 явно не 20
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот смысл атрибутов указанных в [документации](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview):

```
<mat-paginator 
    [length]="100"  // всего записей
    [pageSize]="10"  // записей  на станице сейчас
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" // записей на странице может быть
    aria-label="Select page"
>
```